# What other verbs don't use 'do' in the negative and interrogative?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

I had an English language beginner ask me *"What other verbs, like **'to be'** don't use **'do'** in the negative?"* 
I had never thought about this question from that perspective, and I was a little stumped. I told them about the modals, how **'can'** for instance becomes **'can't'** or **'cannot'** and does not become **'don't can'** but I was trying to find other irregulars that also don't use **'do'** and I couldn't in that moment. Is it just **'to be'** and the modals, or am I missing a huge list?

Comment: All the auxiliary verbs have an extra set of primary forms, i.e. the negative forms, so you need to include auxiliary "have", i.e.  "hadn't" / "hasn't" / "haven't".

Comment: This phenomenon is called **do-support,** and I believe you're correct that  the only exceptions are "to be" and (some) auxiliaries, but I can't seem to find a good source on it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, the [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/228120/91457) by successive suspension was kind of correct. To be and to do are auxiliary verbs with many forms. Like you said, they function in the same way as modal verbs. Therefore, your student's question was so baffling because he/she thought that every sentence needs a "to be" verb to form a question or a negative. However, it is the auxiliary verb that every sentence needs. Therefore, in my opinion, your answer was correct, but it would be better to clarify that "to do", "to be", and the modals are all part of the same group.

As to your question.
There are actually cases when the auxiliary verb is not needed. Particularly with Wh- questions.
Cambridge dictionary mentions that:
When what, who, which or whose is the subject or part of the subject, we do not use the auxiliary. We use the word order subject + verb:

> - What fell off the wall? Which horse won?
> - Who bought this? Whose phone rang?

Also, affirmative Wh- questions also don't need an auxiliary:

> Who wants an ice cream?

This is the only case of interrogative sentences with no auxiliary that I could find.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think this answer is fairly clear. The above is one of there standard comments available to reviewers.

Answer (score -1):

These are the examples which do not need do support  for negatives and interrogatives.

> **You need not come**
>
> **You dare not fight with me**
>
> **I have not got a son**.
>
> **He has not come**
>
> **He had not come.**

-----------'---------------

These are questions without do or does:

> **Need you not come**?
>
> **Dare you not fight with me?**
>
> **Haven't you got a son?**
>
> **Has he not come?**
>
> **Had  he not come?**